# Adding Fastly to a Heroku app does not forward to proper url

Tags: node.js, heroku, dns

I currently have an Heroku app that is being served over a CDN. I have just added Fastly to my Heroku app as an addon and I am struggling to configure it properly. Here is my current configuration:

I have my domain registered on GoDaddy with the following CNAME configuration:

```
Host: www
Points to: my-site-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net
TTL: Custom
Seconds: 600
```

Here is the GoDaddy forwarding configuration (not sure if this matters):

```
Forward to https://www.my-site.io/
(301 & forward only)
```

Here is my fastly configuration:

```
Domains:
my-site-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net
*Provisioned for my-site via Heroku*

my-site.herokuapp.com
*Provisioned for my-site via Heroku*

www.my-site.io
```

And finally in Heroku in the domains configuration section of my app here are my settings:

```
Domain Name: my-site.io
DNS target: darwinian-kumquat-123456.herokudns.com

Domain Name: www.my-site.io
DNS target: serene-trout-123456.herokudns.com
```

Before I tried to make this change I had the CNAME pointing directly to: `serene-trout-123456.herokudns.com` an it was working fine. However after updating this value to the new Fastly value: `my-site-herokuapp-com.global.ssl.fastly.net` Fastly directs the site to `my-site.herokuapp.com` instead of just `https://www.my-site.io`. I followed the instructions listed [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/fastly) so not entirely sure where I have gone wrong. Any ideas?

Comment: Also worth noting that my SSL certificate is uploaded to and managed in Heroku

Comment: What exactly is your purpose? using a cdn to point heroku to custom domain?

Comment: Yes that's right. Ok using a custom domain with Heroku but without a CDN currently, I am trying to introduce a CDN

Answer (score 0):

Probably because you used redirect 301 and you are using the same browser as before before cleaning cache and data.

301 redirects are recomended only for very limited cases: once done the browsers will NOT refresh again any data from the original server.

There are plenty of posts regarding redirection 301, for example:

[Cannot remove 301 redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431164/cannot-remove-301-redirect)

[htaccess 301 redirect - how to disable it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25095470/htaccess-301-redirect-how-to-disable-it?rq=1)

https://www.exai.com/blog/301-redirects

Comment: BTW I discovered this in the hard way... once in production and with every customer having cached the damm redirection... telling customers to clean all data from the browser is not a good solution, but once done...